# Swift Expected Expression in list of Expression Error

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

Im making a basic registration form, and I'm getting multiple "Expected Expression in list of Expression Errors," as well as a couple expected separator errors. Ive tried fixing the errors myself, but I'm new at Swift, and wasn't able to fix it. Any help is appreciated.

```
import UIKit

class RegisterPageViewController: UIViewController {



    @IBOutlet weak var userFullNameTextField: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet weak var userEmailTextField: UITextField!


    @IBOutlet weak var userPasswordTextField: UITextField!


    @IBOutlet weak var userRepeatPasswordTextField: UITextField!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }




    @IBAction func RegisterButtonTapped(sender: AnyObject) {

        let userFullName = userFullNameTextField.text
        let userEmail = userEmailTextField.text
        let userPassword = userPasswordTextField.text
        let userRepeatPassword = userRepeatPasswordTextField.text
    }

        // Check for empty fields


**//ERROR HERE EXPECTED DECLARATION**


        if (((userFullName.isEmpty || userEmail.isEmpty || userPassword.isEmpty || userRepeatPassword.isEmpty))

        {

            // Display alert message

            displayMyAlertMessage("All fields are required")



            return;

        }

        // Check if passwords match

        if(userPassword != userRepeatPassword)

        {
            // Display alert message


            displayMyAlertMessage("Passwords do not match")

            return;


        }



        func displayAlertMessage(userMessage:string)
        {

            var myAlert = UIAlertController(title:"Alert", message: userMessage, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert);



        }






    }

        // Store Data

        // Display alert message with confirmation







    /*
    // MARK: - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    }
    */


}
```

Comment: Perhaps you could add comments in your code as to where these lines are? Since SO code blocks don't include line numbers :0)

Comment: I have added the error position in the comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Error 1: Non-closed parantheses**

You're missing a closing paranthesis in the first `if` statement of the `RegisterButtonTapped` function:

```
if (((userFullName!.isEmpty || userEmail!.isEmpty 
    || userPassword!.isEmpty || userRepeatPassword.isEmpty)) {

    // Display alert message
    displayMyAlertMessage("All fields are required")

    return
}
```

Three left pranthesis `(((` finished by only two right ones `))`. I this case, you really need no set of parantheses at all, but could save one set for readability:

```
if (userFullName!.isEmpty || userEmail!.isEmpty
    || userPassword!.isEmpty || userRepeatPassword.isEmpty) {

        // Display alert message
        displayMyAlertMessage("All fields are required")

        return
}
```

**Error 2: trying to include a function declaration *within* another function**

*(As pointed out by Duy Tran)*

The function `displayAlertMessage(...)` is positioned within the function `RegisterButtonTapped`. Functions may only exists as methods directly in a class/structure etc (or as a global non-class owned function e.g. in a playground).

Hence, you should make sure the function `displayAlertMessage(...)` is placed outside the body of function `RegisterButtonTapped`.

**General remarks**

You should avoid *"forced unwrappings"* of optional variables. E.g. `userFullName!.isEmpty` will lead to a runtime exception in case the optional immutable `userFullName has value`nil`. You should read up on [optionals, optional binding, and so on](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html).

Also note that you needn't put semi-colons `;` after lines in Swift. However you won't get an error for doing so:

- [[swift-evolution] Proposal to remove semicolons](https://lists.swift.org/pipermail/swift-evolution/Week-of-Mon-20151214/002421.html)

Comment: @Swift99 Please try to correct the errors pointed out in the answers and if some errors still persist: update your question with relevant information.

Comment: I have updated the errors. There is still one pending error that isn't fixed, and i have commented it above @dfri

Comment: Could you possibly also update you code to the most recent one? As it is now, the code posted above still contains the errors noted above.

Comment: @Swift99 You if statements are now "without" a function, since you closed `RegisterButtonTapped` function body before them. Anyway, you should probably start with a smaller example and get a grip of the basic concepts of _scopes_. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

The function displayAlertMessage is placed within the IBAction body.

It should be placed outside your IBAction function.